# C# Linq !Any() non detection issue

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have a bit of a weird one. I am running the following code within a game which is called whenever an object is damaged. However, I want to record in MySQL only the first time one object damages another, rather than every single piece of damage. So I put in place a check and a list containing a simple class of two fields, one the damager object name and the other the damaged object name.

```
if (!stats.DamagerList.Any(item => item.DamagedName == actor.Name() && item.DamagerName == initiator.Actor.Name()))
{
    if (!config.DetailedDamageStats)
    {
        Debug.DebugOutput("Adding Damage Suppression entry", 1);
        stats.DamagerList.Add(new AircraftDamager(actor.Name(), initiator.Actor.Name()));
        Debug.DebugOutput("DamagerList now contains:" + stats.DamagerList.Count().ToString() + "Records", 1);
        Debug.DebugOutput("DamagedName:" + actor.Name() + ", DamagerName:"+initiator.Actor.Name() + "", 1);
    }
    stats.AddEventToTable(_event, SortieID, TargetID, EventLabel1, EventLabel2, EventLabel3, EventLabel4);

}
```

However, this isn't working. Somehow I end up with a whole raft of records for the "first" damage, but after that the suppression appears to work. As you can see I've added various Debug statements to try and help identify what the heck is going on and I'm stumped. As far as I can see the code works exactly as intended, except it doesn't.

Kind of hoping this is something **really** obvious that I've overlooked by stupidity.

Comment: Obviously Any() is not the problem,add a breakpoint at the first if statement and see what is inside the DamagerList

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want. What do you mean by *after that the suppression appears to work*? After *what*? If you want to record that one object damaged *any* other object, the `&&` should be `||`. but I'm not sure if that's what you're after.

Comment: @Filburt. The code does compile. I've erroneously left a brace in the cut and paste while removing some variable setting which are unrelated to the purpose at hand.

Comment: @GertArnold I mean after the "whole raft of records". What I **want** is ONE record per damager, damaged pairing. So I shoot you, I should have ONE record, irrespective of whether I hit you ten times. I shoot you again and I should have NO more records.  You shoot me-> I get another ONE record. What's happening now is I get ten records for me shooting you and then nothing subsequent so I belive the suppression is working. Does that make things clearer?

Comment: Could you show your DamageList data as well as the values for actor and initiator?

Comment: Any concurrency involved?

Comment: @GertArnold. Not that I was aware of, but its the only explanation that makes any sense. Unfortunately being embedded in a game, I can't breakpoint and find out what's going on, but I think that's probably what is going on. I've had to solve it another way, by hitting the database to see if the players involved have hit each other. Not nice but it works.